# Are questions regarding software tools and language with limited following out of Stack Overflow scope?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question

The following question, [Can ZeroBrane support the Terra language interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385447/can-zerobrane-support-the-terra-language-interpreter) got two close votes.

Is the question a good fit or is it just too general?

For software and language with moderate following, am I better advised to seek a direct answer from the authors?

My general rule of thumb is that adding questions about the lesser traveled bits benefits both those projects as much as those wanting to give the tool or language a spin.

I cannot find much else to add to the question other than adding lua and LuaJIT tags.

The intent of the question is to scope what needs to happen: write a plugin, use some config file or find out if the feature can even be implemented.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It almost seems like the answers to the questions you're asking are directly in the question you asked, am i misunderstanding? particularly... "Can x support y? i added y as a default language for x" if you can add it as the default language... doesn't that mean yes? or... if not, why?

Comment: @Kevin B Terra interpreter runs fine in ZeroBrane, as far as the lua script getting interpreted. Terra keywords produce an error. Terra is a meta programming language for lua.
I presume your comment relates to the original question rather than the meta one?

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the deleted question. Given these are tech's i'm not familiar with i may be missing the mark, but to me that question didn't really seem all that clear with the way it was structured/worded. We certainly don't disallow new or niche tools/languages. but it can be hard for such cases to gain traction or be understood.

Comment: @Kevin B The author suggests asking questions on Stack Overflow: https://studio.zerobrane.com/community
Terra may fall within the scope of lesser known projects within the lua community.
Perhaps am I advised to be a bit less terse, provide background information for a question which in fine is narrow in scope?

Comment: It sounds like the author of ZeroBrane directs community members to StackOverflow for asking questions. But then you ask a question (admittedly about an interaction with another less common project) and it doesn't get answered? I'm not sure how SO feels about this in general, but I'd be kind of surprised if the general SO community is able to answer (i.e., ZeroBrane project members need to show up to answer such questions, if they want users to ask on SO).

Comment: @Elliott Slaughter I am fine with waiting an entire week to get an answer.
My SO experience with asking the lesser known projects questions is that project leads do monitor and answer those questions.
I favor posting an SO question over asking on the project forum, Discord, IRC, etc. as it does not get SE indexed.
As a consequence, I consider my time and effort in resolving a specific issue get limited traction and network effect.
On the converse it may make business sense to lower moderation standards for the lesser traveled bits.

Comment: Questions about software _tools_ are often borderline. "Can a specific tool do X or Y?" Well, the answer is either yes or no, and that's not really a great answer. SO is also more about writing code, than about configuring certain tools. Questions about configuring IDEs are often accepted, especially if they're popular. So I guess in this case the question was simply borderline _and_ about a tool very few people know, which prompted some to cast down/close votes. In general though, the question isn't off-topic per se, I'd say.

Comment: @deceze I am trying to figure out whether "how" would yield a more conducive question. "Syntax extension system" alludes to how to program ZeroBrane either using a plugin or some form of configuration. Providing more details in the title and body seems to be the consensus?
Would plugin coding be out of scope?
If editor popularity were a factor, would drawing the line turn into a discretionary call?
A SE search on lua editor will turn up ZeroBrane within the first three lines, on SO 387  questions can be found.

Comment: Yes, a "how" question might have prevented some close votes. Do the best you can to research what ZeroBrane _does_ offer, and then ask how to use these things to write a language extension. Something along these lines is surely on-topic. You can hint at being open to solutions which don't require writing any language extensions at all.

Comment: You really shouldn’t ask a question then voluntarily delete it

Comment: Probably the most ideal path for these kind of questions is to first ask "somewhere else", somewhere where devs using the tool congregate and you have the ability to have a back and forth. If the documentation is lacking then it often boils down to necessary research being figuring out the inner workings of the application function; knowing the code, knowing the plugin system, knowing the API, which is context-sensitive. If you can work out what holes there are in the documentation, you have a far better foundation for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Security Hound I reasoned that a single additional close vote would result in not getting an answer. I opted to troubleshoot my question through meta and working on it still.

Comment: I can get the answer possibly within 10 minutes as authors of the lesser traveled bits are usually quite responsive.
I am not sure if updating this meta question in order to summarize key comments is the recommended way to proceed as I need to further research the do's and don'ts of this community.
I suggest reading my reply to @Elliott Slaughter regarding valuable information concerning tier-3, 4 or 5 projects getting buried in forums, Discord and other venues which never seem to get indexed.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about tools used primarily by programmers are explicitly on-topic here. As ZeroBrane is a programming IDE, that makes it on-topic to ask about, regardless of how many or how few programmers may actively use it.

In your *specific* case, it might be better to phrase it as "*How* do I configure ZeroBrane to use the Terralang interpreter?"

If you find out the answer on another site, e.g. from the developers of Terra or of ZeroBrane, you can then come here and post that as an answer to your Stack Overflow question (with proper attribution and in Community Wiki form as necessary).